# SQLite query formatting

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I am working on an SQLite query of which the data is in format

```
col1  | ID   | STATE | col4 | col5
----------------------------------
5     | 10   | LA    | 7    | YES
3     | 11   | FL    | 7    | YES
7     | 12   | LA    | 7    | YES
4     | 13   | DC    | 7    | YES
8     | 14   | FL    | 7    | YES
2     | 15   | GA    | 7    | YES
```

In my data, I have over 50 states but I only need two states and another column having percentage of all others and put the percentages below them. Like how much data is from a particular state as. Here in LA 5% shows that the LA state contains 5% rows from total states and so on.

```
LA  | DC  | Other
-----------------
5%  | 10% | 85%
```

I have tried different methods by searching online or by using answers of StackOverflow but didn't work for me. The below code is showing data in the wrong format and in others, I should have a single value but my query has multiple. I would really appreciate it if anyone can clear my concepts.

```
SELECT State, 
   count(State) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from table) as Percent
FROM 
    table
where 
    State = "LA" 
or 
    State = "DC"
or 
     (State <> "LA" or State <> "DC")
group by 
    State;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg( state = 'LA' ),
       avg( state = 'DC' ),
       avg( state not in ('LA', 'DC') )
from t;
```

SQLite treats booleans as numbers in a number context, with `1` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. It works and my concept is also clear.